# How Java manages with default array value in memory?

Tags: java

I am making some array exercises and I am thinking, is it not a bad thing to put a big number, which makes me sure that my array is not too small, for some written String by user? Is it the same problem as in C++?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = new String [5];
        int letters = 0;
        char[][] array_char = new char [5][letters]; //how to be precise?
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextLine();
        }
```

I am also going to use charAt method to make char2d array for these 5 words.

Comment: Do this enough, and you run out of memory unnecessarily.

Comment: The drawback of arrays is the problem about (re)sizing. If you need a more dynamic size, use a `List`.

Comment: O.K I got it. I will try to use List. I was using dynamic arrays in C++ so I thought that I can make the same thing in Java :D

Comment: In fairness, you shouldn't be writing `new[]` in C++ either. You should be using statically-sized arrays, or an STL container if the size isn't known at compile-time.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code example creates `array_char`, but doesn't use it. By the way, Java allows arrays with zero capacity. So, `array_char`, in your code, is effectively 5 instances of `char` arrays that hold no data.

Comment: Java arrays are of fixed size. Once created, the size can't be changed. If you need to grow an array, you might [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(char%5B%5D,int)) the content to a new array. But, an alternative to an array is a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html), such as an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), which can increase its size when needed.

Comment: The correct approach here is going to be `char[][] array_char = new char[5][];`, without specifying a length, and then setting `array_char[i] = array[i].toCharArray()` later on.

Comment: In fact `String` internally holds some `byte[]` or `char[]` array (version dependent), such that you can simply use `String` to reference the values you need. So `array[i].charAt(k)` will get the `k+1`th character of the `i+1`th `String` in the array. Note that unlike C++, `String` is not default-constructed to an empty value, so the contents of `String[] array` are a series of `null` values. In short, no need to make `array_char` at all, or you can just populate using `#toCharArray` per @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how big your array should be up front, you should probably use a data structure that grows with demand, such as `ArrayList`. That will take care of all internal arrays and memory for you, and you won't need to worry about allocating too much or too little.